# Can multilevel dropdowns be implemented in react-native?

Tags: react-native, dropdown, hybrid-mobile-app

Is multilevel dropdowns/multi level selectors possible in react-native? I want to do a dropdown that has categories and if you tap on that category - subcategories of that category will be show in the dropdown. There is this package (`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multi-level-selector/v/1.0.9`) but it's last publish date is 3 years before, only 4 weekly downloads. I don't think package will work. Even if it works it won't update in future.

I haven't seen multilevel dropdowns in mobile apps.

So multilevel dropdowns doable in react-native?

Comment: The answer is yes, it can be done. If you're asking for a package, that's unfortunately off-topic for SO. If you're asking for code, that's also off-topic; you're supposed to attempt a solution yourself, and come to SO if you're having trouble with the code you've written.

Comment: why code is off limit? Is multilevel dropdowns suitable for a mobile app?

Comment: why code is off topic?**